# Can I install DDR3L RAM in a normal DDR3 socket?

Tags: memory, hardware

Is it possible to install DDR3L RAM in my server that uses DDR3 sockets, will it work? I just want to be sure before spending over €500 on new RAM.

Comment: Yes, see https://superuser.com/questions/1366136/what-does-multiple-voltage-on-ram-memory-mean-it-says-ddr3-1-5v-1-35v

Comment: @MarkWagner Thank you!